# How to ignore auto-generated classes in eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

How to ignore auto-generated classes in eclipse debugger? classes like proxy cglib class, java assists generated classes. EJB3 and EJB2 generated classes. I want debugger to only show classes that have a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked several times and I have never seen nor found a way to explicitly not drop into other src files if you're "stepping into" platform code.

Think about it.. You will need to step around this or create additional breakpoints further downline that allow you to "Resume" out of the platform code and break back into your code.. Make sense.

IMHO, creating plugins and programmatic workarounds for things like this is wrong in that it eliminates the necessity to build the correct knowledge as a proficient debugger that knows how to use the toolset correctly

Comment: i think you just need to ignore "bad" classes. i hope it can be done without writting a plugin for eclipse.

Comment: No, if you step into the platform you will get a "No Source" message. Plus, why go through platform code and other non-pertinent code when the issue is stepping around the platform and back into your code. You could build a plugin that checks for source first and then behaves in the manner you'd like.. But why. That just dummies up the debugger becuase you're not using it correctly.

Comment: but the plugin would just remove the generated classes from the view. why would that be dumming down? i think its just hidding of not needed noice.